# Can't access drive letter after successful network share mapping on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, filesystems, network-shares

I am trying to map a network share to a drive letter persistently on Windows 8.1 (**\server\pictures** to **W:**) and after it succeeds, it is not visible in File Explorer nor can I access it by entering the drive letter on "Run".

However, what's confusing is that the system is telling me that the drive is correctly mapped. I've also verified I'm not running any of the processes as the Administrator account, I'm definitely using my user account (that is in the admin group).

Oddly, if I go to the non-elevated command prompt and run `explorer.exe w:` it will launch file explorer and it will successfully show the drive letter contents.

**Update: The problem is solved if I reboot my PC. After reboot, the drive letter W: then shows in explorer and everything is OK. No idea why a reboot fixes this, so would love to know the root cause.**

Here are screenshots demonstrating the issues and symptoms:

**File explorer not showing the drive letter**
[image: file explorer not showing the drive letter]

**The "Map network drive" feature in File Explorer showing me that's mapped**
[image: The "Map network drive" feature in File Explorer showing me that's mapped]

**Cmd prompt (run as my user account) also showing it's mapped**
[image: Cmd prompt (run as my user account) also showing it's mapped]

**Trying to use "run" to go to the W: drive letter, also fails**
[image: Trying to use "run" to go to the W: drive letter, also fails]

Answer (score 0):

Some discussion here.
http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/322830-windows-8-clients-lose-drive-mapping

May related to UAC setting but I rather believe the stability of windows 8.1, so probably to apply all necessary windows update.